# Find symbolic links in a directory

Tags: find, symlink

How can one recursively find all the symbolic links in a directory in Unix?

Something like this

```
find . -name *.o
```

but for symbolic links along the lines of

```
find . -type symlink ???
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find . -type l
```

Should work.

http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php