# Finding all symbolic links in subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

i am trying to find all symbolic links in a subdirectory in linux. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611595/find-symbolic-links-in-a-directory) but im getting a found of 0 so im doing this:

```
find /bin -type l -fprintf /tmp/symlink "\n"
```

So im putting a return in a file in temp every time i find a symbolic link.
then im trying to count those breaklines to see how many files there are that are symbolic links:

```
wc -l /tmp/syslink
```

but im comming up with 0. does this mean that there are no symbolic links? or am i using the command wrong?

Comment: Superficially, it means there are no symlinks in the system directory `/bin`.  If you meant a sub-directory of your current directory, then you'd specify, for example, `./bin` instead.

Comment: Why make a tmp file? `find /bin -type l | wc -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

find /gamedev -xtype l